# Azure DevOps pipeline upload to FTP after create directory on remote server

Tags: azure-devops

I developed a .net core console application and I want to deliver it to a FTP server.

I managed it in Azure Devops with FTP Upload task. All good here.

But before upload content to FTP, I want to make sure that remote directory exists, if not then create.

I put command `mkdir test` in FTP command but I got error that command is unknown and deployment is not done

[image]

[image]

How to achieve that ?

Comment: How about creating a folder in ftp and give that in Azure Devops and try

Comment: This is not a solution. I want to do automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739366/creating-a-directory-on-remote-ftp-using-powershell) to create directory on FTP. You need to simply define a step before uploading file.

Comment: Awesome, I like solution. Thanks